# code to count the no of times a letter/word occurs in a sentence in python (abs beginner)

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio, loops, counter

questions at the end

```
userinput = input('please enter your sentence here: ')
wannacount = input('which character/word you want to count? ')

# lower casing user input as small & capital letters are not the same in python
lower_in = userinput.lower()
lower_wc = wannacount.lower()

count = 0
for word in lower_in:
    if word == lower_wc:
        count = count +1

# note: words won't be counted with this code, only letters
print(wannacount, 'appears', count, 'times in your sentence')
```

This gives correct answer when only a character is specified. But when I put a word/>=2 characters, the answer is 0.

Questions::

Q1. How to make the desired program which counts word and/or character?

I tried to replace "word" with "lower_wc" and the count gives some seemingly random number. e.g. 11 in "hello world" for char "o".

Q2. What is the logic behind the 11?

Answer (score 0):

**Answer to Q1:**

The following code will help you to count the number of occurrences of a string in another string.  In the *count* function, parameter *text* refers to the string in which you want to search, parameter *to_be_searched* refers to the string you want to search, boolean parameter *case_sensitive* does case-sensitive matching if set to True, and boolean parameter *overlapped* searches for overlapping matches if set to True.

```
import regex

text = "bAnana"
to_be_searched = "ana"

def count(text, to_be_searched, case_sensitive = False, overlapped = False):
    if not case_sensitive:
        to_be_searched = to_be_searched.lower()
        text = text.lower()
    matches = regex.findall(to_be_searched, text, overlapped = overlapped)
    return len(matches)
    
count(text, to_be_searched, case_sensitive = False, overlapped = False) # Ans: 1
count(text, to_be_searched, case_sensitive = False, overlapped = True) # Ans: 2
count(text, to_be_searched, case_sensitive = True, overlapped = False) # Ans: 1
count(text, to_be_searched, case_sensitive = True, overlapped = True) # Ans: 1
```